# how to remove # from url in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to remove the # sign from the url in Angular 6 but I couldn't find any good explanation.
here is my url http://localhost:4200/#/homepage.Is it possible to remove hash from url?

**in app.module.ts**
*{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}*

**in router.ts**

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router,{ useHash: true })

I expect the output is http://localhost:4200/homepage

Comment: Have you tried *not* using the hash location strategy?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that doing so will require you to modify your server http config to support it otherwise on every page refresh you will get a 404..

this is Nginx example:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name <YOUR SERVER DOMAIN>;

access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

index index.html index.htm;

location / {
    root /wwweb/<location to angular dist>/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
}
}
```